# How to call a JSON file using Angular.JS using a local file without a server

Tags: json, angularjs

Here is my controller code:

```
angular.module('navApp', []).controller('blogCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("../json/blogs.json").success(function(response) {$scope.blogs = response.blogs;});
});
```

How can I load the blogs.json? Blogs.json contains two 'blogs'.

Comment: The way you did is fine. Examine the console log and the network panel of the browser dev tools to see what's wrong (the path of the file probably).

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/rjohnson/Desktop/practice/json/blogs.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Shouldn't it be response.data.blogs?

Comment: You can't send AJAX requests if your app is served from the file system. You need a web server to serve your app and the JSON files.

Comment: Thanks! @JBNizet any idea on how I could pull the json file since I don't have a local server running?

Comment: Might want to check up jQuery.parseJSON(). Also for CORS, yeah, you will need something like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida to resolve the URL locally

Comment: @RachelAnn457 set up a local server, and make it run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently chrome does not allow local file access due to its policy, I was able to run this request in Firefox.

Comment: You should use a server to expose the JSON files, then is very straight forward: (here)[http://plnkr.co/edit/5FvKle?p=preview] is a working example